# Centering one image under another vertically and horizontally CSS

Tags: html, css

using the following css/html I have displayed my logo dead centre on screen.

```
img.alignmiddle {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    margin: auto;
}
```

HTML:

```
<a href="http://www.abc.com/home"><img class="alignmiddle" src="abc.png"></a>
```

I now want to add two img buttons( login and register ) underneath the main image.  I would like these two images to appear side by side, centred below the main image.  Can someone help me with the code please?

For example

```
                             M A I N    I M A G E


                               Login   Register
```

Hope that makes sense, appreciate you're all busy people, any help v. much appreciated !

Iggy

Answer (score 1):

Wrap them inside a `<div/>` or whatever:

```
<div id="buttons">
    <a href="#login">Login</a>
    <a href="#trg">Register</a>
</div>
```

Then use this css:

```
#buttons {
    wdth: 200px; /* change to whatever fits */
    margin: 0 auto; /* with a given width this centers a display:block element */
}
```

If you want to center the whole thing horizontally **and** vertically, I would do the following:

First, wrap everything in a `<div/>`:

```
<body>
    <div>
        <div id="home">
            <a href="#">
                <img src="logo.png"/>
            </a>
        </div>
        <div id="buttons">
            <a href="#" id="login">Login</a>
            <a href="#" id="register">Register</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Now, I assume you know the proportions of your buttons. For the example, my logo is 200x100 pixels and my buttons are 145x90 pixels with a `margin` of 10 pixels between. Now, I have the maximum width and height for my wrapper:

```
body > div {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    width: 300px; /* 145 + 10 + 145 */
    height: 200px; /* 100 + 10 + 90 */
    margin-top: -100px;
    margin-left: -150px; /* width * -0.5 */
}
```

Then, I used another wrapper around each line. If you are absolutely sure the proportions won't change, you can go without, but for this exaple I assume you need to be more flexible. First, we make both inner wrappers centering horizontally:

```
body > div > div {
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

This only works with given `width`. So give them a size:

```
#home {
    width: 200px;
    height: 100px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

#buttons {
    width: 300px;
    height: 90px;
}
```

This is the basic. You now have an outer wrapper that centers the whole thing in both directions, and inner wrappers that center horizontally despite their widths. For instance: if your buttons are just 120x90 pixels, correct the `width` of `#buttons` to 120 + 10 (margin) + 120 = `250px`.

The rest is quite straight forward:

```
#login, #register {
    float: left;
    width: 145px;
    height: 90px;
}

#login {
    margin-right: 10px;
}
```

Here is a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2BVMj/1/) which brings all together.

Comment: Hi Guys, thank you very much , the only way I could get it to work to any degree was to wrap all three images in a div with a line break after the first one and assign text-align: center to the whole thing. This puts them almost in the format I was looking for.  Linus you were asking about why absolute positioning. Not a clue total n00b. Was the only piece of code I found which positioned the image centred vertically as well as horizontally.  Unfortunately the code you've given me above doesn't centre the image vertically.  How can I now centre the div containing the three images vertically?

Answer (score 0):

Like this?

http://jsfiddle.net/VqmeG/

Basically it is just

```
text-align: center
```